# How to order and re-order video clips added to iDVD?

Tags: dvd-burning, idvd

I don't think I can find a valid answer for this: how do I actually order or re-order the video clips I added to iDVD?

I actually have video clips named

```
01 some title
02 some other title
03 the third title
04 ...
```

total 11 of them, and I selected all 11 files in Finder, and then dragged them into iDVD.  So the DVD Map showed the correct order of those clips, and Project -> About also showed the assets in the correct order.

However, after the DVD is made, when I was watching program 01, and pressed Next on the DVD set top box remote, then I would see the very beginning of program 04...  Is it out of order?  If so, can it be fixed or changed at all?

Comment: need some more info like what is the date order or size order ?

Comment: I can check... but if I drag the files in with them highlighted in a range, or even if drag them in one by one, and the program would go ahead and sort them by file modification date or file size, I think it would be somewhat unnatural to do

Comment: I do not know what are your settings, so it might be it does that. my questions was what is the file information on #4 as compared to others?

Comment: Ok, I double checked and also used the Magic DVD option to create a disc.  I dragged in the file one by one, and created the disc.  And the clips are still not in the correct order if I press Next on the remote for the set top box DVD player.  Then I checked, the order was not according to the sort order of filesize, not by file modification time (by checking in Bash using  `ls -lt`), not by file creation time (using  `ls -ltU`), not by filename.  So I really wonder what the order is...

Comment: Please clarify, are the files in correct order on the DVD (as burned) using Finder to look. But when you use the DVD play they are not PLAYING in correct order. What DVD player are you using?